# Not being able to run Theano on windows XP 32 with Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, theano

I’m trying to run Theano on windows XP 32 with Anaconda (Python 2.7). I installed Theano following the steps provided in the Anaconda section here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html. Everything went fine but when I try to run the script import theano I get this error message:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. Struggling quite a bit, could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Now I can use Theano on Windows XP 32bits with Anaconda.

With dependency walker, we found when 'import theano', the error 'ImportError' caused by LIBSTDC++6.DLL(a g++ DLL)  cannot import the non-exists symbol 'vsnprintf' in 'MSVCRT.DLL'.

The key to fix this issue is, replace the mingw installed by 'conda install mingw' (rev 4.7.0). Install mingw g++ (rev 4.9.3) with '[mingw-get-setup.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/)' from sourceforge instead.

Make user you PATH environment has 'C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\lib;' (default install location) to use the correct g++.

Good luck!